# UnsupportedOperationException when using KeyStore.getEntry()?

Tags: java, security, macos, exception, keystore

I'm trying to retrieve entries from a Java KeyStore on Mac OSX 10.6.  My code runs fine on Windows and Linux, but when I run it on OSX I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:466)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1261)
```

Here's my code:

```
String keyStorePath = ...
PasswordProtection pp = new PasswordProtection("password".toCharArray());
CallbackHandlerProtection chp = new CallbackHandlerProtection(
        new CallbackHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Callback[] callbacks)
                    throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
                for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
                    if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback) {
                        PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
                        pc.setPassword("password".toCharArray());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

try {
    KeyStore.Builder kb = Builder.newInstance("JCEKS", null, new File(
            keyStorePath), chp);
    KeyStore ks = kb.getKeyStore();

    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        String alias = aliases.nextElement();
        KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry(alias, chp);

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any idea why this exception is being thrown on OSX?  Is it a bug in the JVM on this OS?  Anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a bug in Apple's implementation of the JVM.  I've submitted a bug report.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation of `KeyStoreSpi.java` at line 466 reveals the following:

```
public KeyStore.Entry engineGetEntry(String alias, ...) throws ... {

    ...

    if (protParam instanceof KeyStore.PasswordProtection) {
        if (engineIsCertificateEntry(alias)) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException
                ("trusted certificate entries are not password-protected");
        } else if ...
    }

    ...
}
```

There you have the exact conditions for which it throws the exception.

So when does `engineIsCertificateEntry(alias)` return true?

According to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStoreSpi.html#engineIsCertificateEntry%28java.lang.String%29) it does so...

> ... *if the entry identified by the given alias was created by a call to `setCertificateEntry`, or created by a call to `setEntry` with a `TrustedCertificateEntry`*

The method is however abstract, so it is hard to dig further without knowing the exact implementation being used. According to your description, the logic seems to differ slightly between implementations.